# Understanding how to satisfy borrow checker when calling method on iterator twice?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

In the below code, I understand that a borrow has been done by the call of `zipped.filter`.  What I don't understand is how to fix it, if I want to use `zipped` again later.

I'm new to Rust, so if there are other problems or strange misuse of idioms in this code, I'm interested in that as well, but primarily about how to make the borrow work twice here.

Code:

```
fn main() {
    let data : Vec<String> = vec!["abc".to_string(), "def".to_string(), "bbc".to_string()];

    for s1 in &data {
        for s2 in &data {
            let zipped = s2.chars().zip(s1.chars());

            // Did a diff of the two strings have only one character different?
            if zipped.filter(|(a,b)| a != b).count() == 1 {
                let newStr = zipped.filter(|(a,b)| a == b).map(|(a,_)| a).collect::<String>();

                println!("String without the different character: {}", newStr);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `zipped`
   --> a.rs:10:30
    |
6   |             let zipped = s2.chars().zip(s1.chars());
    |                 ------ move occurs because `zipped` has type `Zip<Chars<'_>, Chars<'_>>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
...
9   |             if zipped.filter(|(a,b)| a != b).count() == 1 {
    |                       ---------------------- `zipped` moved due to this method call
10  |                 let newStr = zipped.filter(|(a,b)| a == b).map(|(a,_)| a).collect::<String>();
    |                              ^^^^^^ value used here after move
    |
note: this function consumes the receiver `self` by taking ownership of it, which moves `zipped`

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0382`.
```

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to accomplish with the code?

Comment: What the code does isn't particularly relevant to the question, just assume that I want to do some iterator operations (e.g. `filter`, etc) on `zipped` two different times :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always `zipped.clone()`, which clones the iterator so that you move the clone when you first call to `filter(...).count()`. The original `zipped` remains untouched and you'll move it by the second `filter(...).collect()` .

Note that it doesn't clone any data because iterators are lazy, copying an iterator means to copy its logic (so it copies logic of `.chars()`, `.zip()` etc which is just a bunch of function pointers, not the data).

```
fn main() {
    let data : Vec<String> = vec!["abc".to_string(), "def".to_string(), "bbc".to_string()];

    for s1 in &data {
        for s2 in &data {
            let zipped = s2.chars().zip(s1.chars());
            
            // << THE CHANGE IS HERE
            if zipped.clone().filter(|(a,b)| a != b).count() == 1 {
                let newStr = zipped.filter(|(a,b)| a == b).map(|(a,_)| a).collect::<String>();

                println!("String without the different character: {}", newStr);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
String without the different character: bc
String without the different character: bc
```

Comment: I see.  So the performance implications of cloning an iterator are minimal, e.g. it's just the state for the iterator that's cloned, and not any data?  

Is the compiler complaining about the two calls in my code because `filter` could have modified `zipped` or somthing?

Comment: It compiles just fine, take a look on a [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=265b332af4f8c13a1cd533dc6cfb5e68)

Comment: @Tumbleweed53 `filter` *consumes* the iterator and makes a new iterator from it so you can't use it again. And even if it didn't by using `by_ref`, `count` would run it till the end meaning the second usage would return nothing.

Comment: @kmdreko Thanks that makes sense.  I need to remember it's not a collection, it's an iterator.  Which can be moved one direction.